# Versions and indistinguishability, when to distinguish?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

$\textit{The stochastic processes X and Y are called a modification or versions of each other if}$
\begin{align}
P(X(t) = Y(t)) = 1 \quad \textit{for all t $\in$ I}
\end{align}

$\textit{The stochastic processes X and Y are called indistinguishable}$
\begin{align}
P(X(t) = Y(t) \,\,\,\textit{for all $t \in I$}) = 1
\end{align}

I am trying to come up with scenarios when the distinction between versions and indistinguishable procsses becomes relevant.

In other words, are there some situation when we cannot change to a version without messing things up? And where if we would stick to an indistinguishable change we would be in the clear?

I am also looking for  a situation where the former change is possible.

Examples from applications are also of interest, not just theoretical.

Comment: What is you definition of "version"? (In your terminology, is there also "modification"?)

Comment: @maliesen Yes indeed.

Comment: You should add definitions of the terms.

Comment: @Olorun ok, done.

Comment: Also, one may define processes to be versions of each other, if they are distributed according to the same law. (i.e. they share the same marginal distributions.) This concept you have _not_ in mind, right?

Comment: @maliesen I think that is weaker? Or is this something else the  finite dimrnsional distributions? Are you refering to a measue on the space of space of contious functions?

Comment: @Speaker Yes indeed.

Comment: @maliesen I dont understand. Which of my suggestions got a "Yes"?